# geotools : Could not find element declaration for

Tags: xml, kml, geotools

I don't find solution of my issue.
I try to create a KMl file using geotools.

I 'm stuck :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools.xsd</groupId>
            <artifactId>xsd</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools.xsd</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-xsd-kml</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools.xsd</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-xsd-core</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

And for the java source code I have the common example :

```
final Encoder lEncoder = new Encoder(new KMLConfiguration());
final FileOutputStream lFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
lEncoder.setIndenting(true);
lEncoder.encode(featureCollection, KML.kml, lFileOutputStream);
lFileOutputStream.close();
```

and I have this issue :
"Could not find element declaration for:{http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1}kml"
And apparently I don't have the good xml type library.
Which one is missing ?
Or maybe it's another issue...

Thank a lot for your answer !
Alban

Comment: what is featureCollection?